# ¿ Porque el dev c++ me da error al abrir un proyectos con múltiples main y así les cambie el nombre solo se me ejecuta el primer main?

Tags: c++, dev-c++, c++17

Hola soy un estudiante de programación y ultimamente he tenido problemas con mi editor de texto (Dev c++) es a la hora de ejecutar varios mains dentro de un mismo proyecto

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image]

Este error siempre me aparece cuando voy a ejecutar un proyecto con múltiples main y cuando le cambio el nombre a los main en el proyecto solo me ejecuta el principal así quiera abrir otro cpp (como el ejercicio 3) me abre solo el main principal o el primer main, ya le pregunte a mi profesora y me dice que es un problema mío debido a una instalación mal hecha pero ya lo reinstale con varios tutoriales de youtube y lo reinstale con el full o safe del instalador y hasta desinstale y reinicie el pc y luego lo instale no creo que sea un error de la instalación

En fin mis dudas a resolver son ¿Es normal que un proyecto en dev c++ al tener varios main de este error? y si no es así ¿como lo resuelvo?, y la otra pregunta seria como compilo y ejecuto un solo cpp del proyecto (abierto) sin que me de un error o que se abra solo el principal?

**PD:** Encontre una forma algo complicada de solucionarlo que es salirme del proyecto ponerle al cpp que quiero abrir como main y compilo y ejecuto y me corre pero ¿como hago para abrir un solo cpp teniendo el proyecto abierto?.

Perdón por extenderme mucho pero quiero ser los mas especifico posible

Comment: ¿Por qué un cpp tendría más de un método main? La especificación define que main es el entrypoint y por tanto, único [(más info)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3974851/236345). Lo que se podría es ponerlos [en namespaces diferentes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1991498/236345)

Comment: Por favor, no publiques imágenes del código. Especialmente imágenes pequeñas. No puedo ver nada. Código es texto, por favor publícalo como texto. ¡Gracias!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Por convención, main es el punto de entrada. Es la función que se empieza a ejecutar cuando empiezas el programa. Entonces, si hay varios main, la maquina no sabe por donde empezar el programa, y te tira error.

Si tu plan es ejecutar uno detrás de otro, puedes llamar uno adentro de otro

```cpp
int main2(void) {}

int main(void) {
   main2();
   return 0;
}
```

Ahora, si son varios main, porque lo quieres compliar en varios ejecutables a la vez, vas a tener que compilar individualmente cada .cpp